# Alternative to xamarin community toolkit toucheffect maui

Tags: touch, maui, touch-event

does anybody knows if there is a workaround for using long touch with DotNet MAUI?
In my legacy app build with Xamarin, i was using xct:TouchEffect.LongPressCommand.

As far as i know there is a wip in MAUI community toolkit  but it's not avalaible at this time.

Maybe using EventToCommandBehaviour?
What will be the name of the event if i use this?

Is there a way to extend for exemple ImageHandler with propertyMapper and CommandMapper to achieve this goal?
Maybe someone has an other idea?
Thanks by advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be fantastic to have the long touch effect with .Net MAUI and there is a [proposal on Github](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/86) to include this in the [MAUI Community Toolkit](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui).According to the thread update, it'll be implemented soon.

As an alternative workaround, you can try to find the handler of the MAUI control, then acquire `handler.PlatformView` which is a native control. After that, you can invoke native control methods, and subscribe to native control events such as the gesture event, see [Customize .NET MAUI controls with handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize#customize-a-control) and refer to the following code:

**Customize a control with a mapper(be effective on an Image control):**

```
 Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ImageHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>  
{  
#if WINDOWS  
            handler.PlatformView.Holding += PlatformView_Holding;  
  
#endif  
#if ANDROID  
            handler.PlatformView.LongClick += PlatformView_LongClick;  
  
#endif  
#if IOS  
  
            handler.PlatformView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;  
            handler.PlatformView.AddGestureRecognizer(new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(HandleLongClick));  
#endif  
});
```

**Implement Long press event in each platform:**

```
#if WINDOWS  
    private void PlatformView_Holding(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)  
    {  
        //Touch can produce a Holding action, but mouse devices generally can't.  
        //see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.holding?view=winrt-22621  
    }  
#endif  
#if IOS  
    private void HandleLongClick(UILongPressGestureRecognizer sender)  
    {  
        //raise longpress event 
    }  
#endif  
#if ANDROID  
    private void PlatformView_LongClick(object sender, Android.Views.View.LongClickEventArgs e)  
    {  
        //raise longpress event 
    }  
#endif
```

**Update:**

```
public class TestPageViewModel 
{

        public TestPageViewModel() {

            ModifyImage();
        }



        void ModifyImage()
        {
            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ImageHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
            {

#if WINDOWS

                  handler.PlatformView.Holding += PlatformView_Holding;  
  
#endif

#if ANDROID
                handler.PlatformView.LongClick += PlatformView_LongClick;

#endif
#if IOS
  
                  handler.PlatformView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;  
                  handler.PlatformView.AddGestureRecognizer(new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(HandleLongClick));  
#endif

            });
        }

#if WINDOWS
    private void PlatformView_Holding(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)  
      {  
        //Touch can produce a Holding action, but mouse devices generally can't.  
        //see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.holding?view=winrt-22621  
         
    }  
#endif
#if IOS
    private void HandleLongClick(UILongPressGestureRecognizer sender)  
    {  
         //raise longpress event and then call the command here
    }  
#endif
#if ANDROID
        private void PlatformView_LongClick(object sender, Android.Views.View.LongClickEventArgs e)
        {
             //raise longpress event and then call the command here
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

Reference link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/900859/long-press-in-net-maui

Comment: Thanks for that !! Do you know if there is a way to call a command from the viewmodel, in the "handlelongclick" methods ?

Comment: Thanks for the update, you may need to put the maui handler in your viewmodel and then call the command from `handlelongclick`.